# Do optimised calls to memcpy@plt respect restrictions on instruction sets?

Tags: c++, memcpy, libstdc++, gcc7, gcc11

In c++ I have the following piece of code, that is optimised in assembly to call memcpy.

```
void do_something(big_struct& a, const big_struct& b)
{
   a = b;
}
```

```
 lea    rdi,[rsi+0x4]
 mov    edx,0x220
 lea    rsi,[rbx+0x18]
 call   7ead40 <memcpy@plt>
```

Looking at the implementation of memcpy, it looks like libstdc++ provides several different versions with different restrictions based on supported instruction sets.  From other questions I believe the specific implementation chosen is deferred to runtime.

If I compile with gcc and link with flags that restrict the instruction set used, for example '-mno-avx', assuming the CPU this binary is run on supports avx, will the specific implementation of memcpy chosen still respect this decision?

Comment: libstdc++ does not provide `memcpy` at all. `memcpy` is part of the C standard library implemention, i.e. glibc, musl, uclib, or whichever you are using. It is independent independent of compiler and C++ standard library implementation.

Comment: So you first need to specify which C standard library implementation you are asking about or alternatively which OS and distribution (so it can be deduced).

Comment: Also, typically the C standard library is linked in dynamically, so that code matching the target system, not the build system, will be used. Generally, the memcpy implementation will then be compiled with the flags that were given when building that system's libc. Your build flags will not matter and typically there are not multiple implementations to choose from at runtime. In the case of glibc there is a mechanism to choose different implementations at runtime, but I don't expect it to somehow incorporate build flags at the call site. It will detect the running CPU features instead.

Comment: Things will be different when linking the libc statically.